# Runtime.getRuntime().exec() create Database via file.sql in Java Program

Tags: java, mysql

Welcome to all

In command line the command

```
mysql -u root -pPass < configBase.sql
```

configure my base from the file configBase.sql.
How can I do it with java language ?

Comment: You forgot to include, in your question, what happens and what you expect to happen instead.

Comment: I would like to get an effect in Java code that I can get through command line : 
mysql -u root -pMyPass < MyConfigFile.sql
 which will inject into the database the commands taken from the MyConfigFile.sql file.

In java I wrote a format with JButton, and after clicking on the button it calls ActionListener() with Runtime.getRuntime().exec() method.
and I'd like to get the effect of the command line.
arrays, user etc.

Comment: Unfortunately my attempts didn't bring the expected results, because the code I presented only logs into MySql database, and I would like it to redirect commands from MyConfigFile.sql file, which will create database,